# Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int - Can't find my Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, integer

This is my Code:

```
<?php
/**
* Displays the sum of the last 30 day donations.
*
* @author Miro F.
* @copyright 2015 majoess
* @license GNU Lesser General Public License
<http://opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-license.php>
*/


$db_host = ""; // Datenbank Server (IP-Adresse ohne Port)
$db_passwort = ""; // Passwort für den Datenbank Account
$db_username = ""; // Nutzername für die Datenbank
$db_datenbank = ""; // Datenbankname


$mysqlq_connection = mysqli_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_passwort, $db_datenbank);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Datenbank-Verbindung fehlgeschlagen!";
    exit();
}

$abfrage = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `shop1_product_order` WHERE subject = 'shop.global.subject.balance' AND status = '1' AND date > TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day))";
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($mysqlq_connection, $abfrage);






//Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background-color:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bold}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:0.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-0.5em}sub{bottom:-0.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace, monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:bold}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}html{font-size:10px;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#333;background-color:#fff}input,button,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}a{color:#337ab7;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:focus{color:#23527c;text-decoration:underline}a:focus{outline:thin dotted;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px}figure{margin:0}img{vertical-align:middle}.img-responsive{display:block;max-width:100%;height:auto}.img-rounded{border-radius:6px}.img-thumbnail{padding:4px;line-height:1.42857143;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;display:inline-block;max-width:100%;height:auto}.img-circle{border-radius:50%}hr{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee}.sr-only{position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;margin:-1px;padding:0;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0, 0, 0, 0);border:0}.sr-only-focusable:active,.sr-only-focusable:focus{position:static;width:auto;height:auto;margin:0;overflow:visible;clip:auto}[role="button"]{cursor:pointer}@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0}to{background-position:0 0}}@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0}to{background-position:0 0}}@keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0}to{background-position:0 0}}.progress{overflow:hidden;height:20px;margin-bottom:20px;background-color:#f5f5f5;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}.progress-bar{float:left;width:0%;height:100%;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;color:#fff;text-align:center;background-color:#337ab7;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);-webkit-transition:width .6s ease;-o-transition:width .6s ease;transition:width .6s ease}.progress-striped .progress-bar,.progress-bar-striped{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);-webkit-background-size:40px 40px;background-size:40px 40px}.progress.active .progress-bar,.progress-bar.active{-webkit-animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;-o-animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite}.progress-bar-success{background-color:#5cb85c}.progress-striped .progress-bar-success{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)}.progress-bar-info{background-color:#5bc0de}.progress-striped .progress-bar-info{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)}.progress-bar-warning{background-color:#f0ad4e}.progress-striped .progress-bar-warning{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)}.progress-bar-danger{background-color:#d9534f}.progress-striped .progress-bar-danger{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content:" ";display:table}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.center-block{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.pull-right{float:right !important}.pull-left{float:left !important}.hide{display:none !important}.show{display:block !important}.invisible{visibility:hidden}.text-hide{font:0/0 a;color:transparent;text-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;border:0}.hidden{display:none !important}.affix{position:fixed}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="widget" name="widget" style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%; margin-top: 25%; margin-bottom: 25%;">
<b style="margin-bottom: 2%; font-size: 20px;"><center>Aktueller Spendenmonat <i><?php echo date('F'); ?></i></center></b><br>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $ergebnis * 2;?>40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo $ergebnis * 2;?>40%">
    <?php echo "<b>" . $ergebnis * 2 . "</b>";?> von 50€.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can find my failture... Because for me it looks like everythink should work! This is the HTML-Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background-color:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bold}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:0.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-0.5em}sub{bottom:-0.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace, monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:bold}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}html{font-size:10px;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#333;background-color:#fff}input,button,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}a{color:#337ab7;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:focus{color:#23527c;text-decoration:underline}a:focus{outline:thin dotted;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px}figure{margin:0}img{vertical-align:middle}.img-responsive{display:block;max-width:100%;height:auto}.img-rounded{border-radius:6px}.img-thumbnail{padding:4px;line-height:1.42857143;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;display:inline-block;max-width:100%;height:auto}.img-circle{border-radius:50%}hr{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee}.sr-only{position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;margin:-1px;padding:0;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0, 0, 0, 0);border:0}.sr-only-focusable:active,.sr-only-focusable:focus{position:static;width:auto;height:auto;margin:0;overflow:visible;clip:auto}[role="button"]{cursor:pointer}@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0}to{background-position:0 0}}@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0}to{background-position:0 0}}@keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0}to{background-position:0 0}}.progress{overflow:hidden;height:20px;margin-bottom:20px;background-color:#f5f5f5;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}.progress-bar{float:left;width:0%;height:100%;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;color:#fff;text-align:center;background-color:#337ab7;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);-webkit-transition:width .6s ease;-o-transition:width .6s ease;transition:width .6s ease}.progress-striped .progress-bar,.progress-bar-striped{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);-webkit-background-size:40px 40px;background-size:40px 40px}.progress.active .progress-bar,.progress-bar.active{-webkit-animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;-o-animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite}.progress-bar-success{background-color:#5cb85c}.progress-striped .progress-bar-success{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)}.progress-bar-info{background-color:#5bc0de}.progress-striped .progress-bar-info{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)}.progress-bar-warning{background-color:#f0ad4e}.progress-striped .progress-bar-warning{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)}.progress-bar-danger{background-color:#d9534f}.progress-striped .progress-bar-danger{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content:" ";display:table}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.center-block{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.pull-right{float:right !important}.pull-left{float:left !important}.hide{display:none !important}.show{display:block !important}.invisible{visibility:hidden}.text-hide{font:0/0 a;color:transparent;text-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;border:0}.hidden{display:none !important}.affix{position:fixed}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="widget" name="widget" style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%; margin-top: 25%; margin-bottom: 25%;">
<b style="margin-bottom: 2%; font-size: 20px;"><center>Aktueller Spendenmonat <i>October</i></center></b><br>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\life.kbs-altis.de\forum\spendenuebersicht.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />
240" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\life.kbs-altis.de\forum\spendenuebersicht.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />
240%">
    <br />
<b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\life.kbs-altis.de\forum\spendenuebersicht.php</b> on line <b>51</b><br />
```

Why should I convert my mysqli-result to int, if the "mysqli-result" is an int of the database 'amount'?

Comment: var_dump($row); effects to: array(1) { ["SUM(amount)"]=> NULL }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query` does not return your number directly. It returns a `mysqli_result` as you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

To get the row you have parsed, you should fetch it first:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
```

A lot of information on using mysqli can be found [here](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17).

Comment: The same error. I dont know if im doing this right. @Satisfaction

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ergebnis);

Then i replaced    $ergebnis with    $row

Comment: Just try dumping out (var_dump or similar) the result that you get after mysqli_fetch-assoc(). You should be getting an associated array.

Comment: array(1) { ["SUM(amount)"]=> NULL }

Comment: Well, there are no amounts set in the database then, at least for that exact query that you're doing.

Comment: But there are more than 300 values... maybe is my query wrong? the column 'date' is in unix timecode

Comment: Try running the query outside of PHP, like in PHPMyAdmin or whatever tool you use.