# How compare the result from count(*) with INT in php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, count

I want to compare the result for count(*) with INT. This is my code;

```
 $sql_check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hd";
 $result_check = mysqli_query($link, $sql_check) or die ("ERR");

 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_check);
 if($row == 1)
 {...}
```

It seem like there is no error. I tried to run it but it skip my if statement. If I tried to

```
echo $row
```

It show error

> NOTICE: Array to string conversion

If I used code

```
 $sql_check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hd";
 $result_check = mysqli_query($link, $sql_check) or die ("ERR");

 $row = int($result_check);
 if($row == 1)
 {...}
```

It show  error

> NOTICE: Object of class msqli_result could not converted to int

I have tried to used the answers from previous questions that have been asked before this (same question) but it doesn't work. Can you help me? Please I really need to know where my false.

Thankyou for helping.

Some other questions (that have been asked) and I have tried it but it seem does not work for me:
1. [Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int and all entries return true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437768/object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-int-and-all-entries-retu)
2. [mysqli_result could not be converted to int in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970565/mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-int-in)
3. [Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int - Can't find my Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434384/object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-int-cant-find-my-erro)
4. [Convert SQL query object into integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476475/convert-sql-query-object-into-integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this, not sure if it solves the problem!

```
   $sql_check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hd as 'res'";
     $result_check = mysqli_query($link, $sql_check) or die ("ERR");

     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_check);
     if($row['res'] == 1)
     {...}
```

OR YOU CAN TRY THIS

```
 $sql_check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hd as 'res'";
 $result_check = mysqli_query($link, $sql_check) or die ("ERR");

 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_check);
 if((int)$row['res'] == 1)
 {...}
```

Comment: I have tried your answers. It seem there no any error. But why it still not  read my error message in the if statement? But if i put echo in that if & else statement, it show the output for both statement and does not check the condition at if statement. Do you know why? @Ashraf D. Milhim

Comment: Oh nvm. I have try to use another way to popup and it work with your code. Thankyou for helping @Ashraf D. Milhim